# Images are not displaying in https while they are showing up with http

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, apache, express

I have built my first personal website(MERN stack). It was working fine in development mode on my machine. I am trying to deploy it using AWS Lightsail. Everything seems to be working fine in https except the images are not displaying. When I click on images to open in new tab it displays in http mode.

Front-end port: 3000

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/images/image_name.jpeg";
```

Images are stored on backend on port 8000/images folder.

I have been stuck on this problem for 3 days now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have proper ssl certs and https setup for your backend connections? Also https does not work on port 8000.

Comment: Hey @Marcin, I have configured the conf files in the lightsail instance which routes request on 443 to front end(3000). Setup seems to be fine as site shows no ssl error while performing CRUD operations except for the images folder in the backend is not redirecting to https.

Comment: Setup was the problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers block loading content through http if the page that's embedding them is loaded through https. Use the same protocol for both, and you're set.

Instead of explicitly using `http://example.com/image.jpg` or `https://example.com/image.jpg`, you can also use protocol-relative URLs like `//example.com/image.jpg`, or just `/image.jpg` of course.

Comment: I had tried to use what you suggested before. When using https, images do not display at all. "Can't provide a secure connection".